# GKE Mulitple networking

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I don’t find in GKE documentation a reference for supporting Multus or IPVLAN attachement, all I find is related to Anthos on baremetal

Could you please give us some indications how multi-networking is supported for Pods running on GKE?

First is first can I have GKE nodes with multiple NIcs attached?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you're looking for? Does this help answer your question? https://serverfault.com/questions/1078635/how-is-gcp-gke-vpc-native-cluster-ip-alias-implemented

Comment: @Cpt.Whale , no actually what I am looking for is having two network interfaces on GKE nodes ?

Comment: No, nodes only have one interface, but they can get additional IP addresses